# Colors less saturated in Snow Leopard Finder, Preview & Safari than in Chrome -- why?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, adobe-photoshop, finder, jpeg, color-profiles

If I look at the picture here in Safari, Preview or the finder, the shades of blue are significantly different than if I look at the picture in Google Chrome (they are less saturated than in Chrome).

[image]

Since I am a photographer and need to prepare pictures for publication online, I need to know what a jpeg should really look like, in order to color-correct it.

I have an excellent Eizo monitor that is correctly calibrated.

If I open the same image in Photoshop CS3, I get the Chrome colors if I use **Monitor RGB** under **view >> proof setup**, and I get the Safari colors if I use **Macintosh RGB**.

Can anyone explain the difference between these two settings, and the difference between Safari and Chrome? Which colors are correct?

Photos that I prepared under Windows (during the past five years) now seem washed out in the Apple Finder and Preview, even though I had correctly prepared them.

Is there a setting on the Macintosh for color calibration, besides the monitor calibration control panel?

Comment: Update: I tried saving the same image from Photoshop after assigning a different profile, and the two images display differently in the Finder. So my guess is that all the Apple software uses embedded profiles, whereas Chrome just ignores them.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? As I understand it, you found out the same thing shortly after I posted it..?

Comment: Your answer is correct, and it was a help. I'm sorry for not coming back sooner. I didn't mark it correct because I wanted to post a more complete answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing issues with color management, which not all browser support properly. See, for example, [here](http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/article_pages/web-browser-color-management.html).

Your test image has the same colors in Chrome and Safari on my Mac though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself, but I'm still open to new information if anyone wants to chime in.

The answer is simply that Apple software (and Photoshop) uses any color profile included with JPG images whereas Chrome and probably most other consumer software packages does not.

My camera was saving pictures with a color profile that caused the images to appear washed out when viewed in the expected color space.

The answer as to which is correct is that the Safari / Macintosh RGB colors are correct -- they reflect a correct handling of the image file and its accompanying color profile.

The results in Chrome are wrong -- the browser can't handle color profiles correctly.